# Windows CMD Batch, START, output redirection, but appending

Tags: command-line, batch

i currently have issues with output redirection of cmd.

I use "start" command to call another wayne.bat and want its output to be redirected. This works, but everytime i start my .bat (what happens daily), the "old" log file is discarded, so it will not append after restarting the .bat.

my command:

```
start /min wayne.bat run ^> logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

Works like intended. Now the mode "appending" is usually enabled by using ">>" instead of ">", so i tried:

```
start /min wayne.bat run ^>> logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

what causes the script to instantly stop without any error message, even if called over the shell. Without the escaping character "^" it doesn't work either.

So, how can i use the "start"-command to start a script and redirect its output in a appending manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
start /min wayne.bat run ^>^> logs\log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: *head -> desk* if i need to escape a single ">", i should escape the other one too -.- that is too obvious! Thanks for that! =]